# Android 3.0.1 does not resolve dependency

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I want to add those dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.andrognito.pinlockview:pinlockview:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.multidots:fingerprint-auth:1.0.1'
```

in android studio 3.0.1 with gradle 3.0.1 but I get the following error:

> Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.multidots:fingerprint-auth:1.0.1.
>   Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.andrognito.pinlockview:pinlockview:2.1.0.

My `build.gradle` files are:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        google()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And the other one:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.b.jacob.gallery"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    implementation 'com.andrognito.pinlockview:pinlockview:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.multidots:fingerprint-auth:1.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

It's important to say that those dependencies resolve without any problem in older version of android studio.

Comment: Could you try changing jcenter(),mavenCentral(),google() repositories order with google one first

Answer (score 0):

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
```

and

```
 buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
```

cannot go together there will be a **conflict**

Your changes should be  :-

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.0.2'
```

and

```
compileSdkVersion 26
```

**Note**

Dont forget to make sure **Offline Work** is *unchecked* in android studio...and **you are connected to internet**

These are the probable reasons why the dependencies cant be resolved !!

Comment: When I sync, Gradle try to resolve modules from this link: https://dl-google.com/dl/maven2/com/multidots/fingerprint-auth/1.0.1/fingerprint-auth-1.0.1.pom Why does gradle use this this link? I think problem is here.What do you think?

Comment: because Gradle tries to download the open-source app from maven through the link !! @CMaster its perfectly fine !! it can be caused if your offline work is enabled !!